# 2 Marketing Cloud Connectors / Environments integrated to 1 Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I'm facing a bit of a unique situation where I'm migrated an existing SFMC Environment (V1) to a new SFMC Environment (V1). Both V1 and V2 are on the same stack.

V1 is currently integrated through SFMC Connector to Salescloud (PROD) using integration user V1

I want to integrate the new SFMC_V2 Environment using a separate V2 User.
For the moment, I just want to enable the Syncronised Data Extensions in the SFMC_v2 environment, whilst SFMC_v1 Environment continues to send etc. The SFMC_v2 environment will be a 1 way.

Has anyone any experience in doing similar? Is it feasible and what are any pitfalls ?

(i have read through Multi-order connect etc - but dosn't mention anything on multiple SFMC environments).

Answer (score 0):

I believe your scenario is depicted in the documentation here on the far right - 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_multi_org_account_and_user_configuration.htm&type=5

...which is not supported. I do not believe your scenario of running two parallel SFMCs connected to one Sales Cloud Org is feasible through SFMC Multi-org.

Marketing Clouds being on the same stack does not change the fact that you are dealing with two separate marketing cloud environments ("Enterprise 2.0 Accounts" in the doc).

This means that at some point in time you have to "flick the switch".
Hope this helps?